# Issue with Spyder when executing the command 'conda list'

Tags: anaconda, conda, spyder

I installed Anaconda to use Spyder, but when executing the 'conda list' command in the Spyder terminal, I encounter this error:

```
conda list
Traceback (most recent call last):

  Cell In[7], line 1
    get_ipython().run_line_magic('conda', 'list')

  File C:\ProgramData\anaconda4\Lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py:2456 in run_line_magic
    result = fn(args, **kwargs)

  File C:\ProgramData\anaconda4\Lib\site-packages\IPython\core\magics\packaging.py:30 in wrapper
    return func(args, **kwargs)

  File C:\ProgramData\anaconda4\Lib\site-packages\IPython\core\magics\packaging.py:128 in conda
    conda = _get_conda_like_executable("conda")

  File C:\ProgramData\anaconda4\Lib\site-packages\IPython\core\magics\packaging.py:53 in _get_conda_like_executable
    match = re.search(

  File C:\ProgramData\anaconda4\Lib\re__init.py:176 in search
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)

  File C:\ProgramData\anaconda4\Lib\re__init.py:294 in _compile
    p = _compiler.compile(pattern, flags)

  File C:\ProgramData\anaconda4\Lib\re_compiler.py:743 in compile
    p = _parser.parse(p, flags)

  File C:\ProgramData\anaconda4\Lib\re_parser.py:982 in parse
    p = _parse_sub(source, state, flags & SRE_FLAG_VERBOSE, 0)

  File C:\ProgramData\anaconda4\Lib\re_parser.py:457 in _parse_sub
    itemsappend(_parse(source, state, verbose, nested + 1,

  File C:\ProgramData\anaconda4\Lib\re_parser.py:865 in _parse
    p = _parse_sub(source, state, sub_verbose, nested + 1)

  File C:\ProgramData\anaconda4\Lib\re_parser.py:457 in _parse_sub
    itemsappend(_parse(source, state, verbose, nested + 1,

  File C:\ProgramData\anaconda4\Lib\re_parser.py:541 in _parse
    code = _escape(source, this, state)

  File C:\ProgramData\anaconda4\Lib\re_parser.py:440 in _escape
    raise source.error("bad escape %s" % escape, len(escape))

error: bad escape \P
```

I tried to install Jedi and Parso but it didn't work:
`pip uninstall jedi pip uninstall parso pip install parso==0.5.2 pip install jedi==0.15.2`
I installed Anaconda on another computer and everything worked fine, but I have no idea how to solve this.